# Observers and threads

Tags: java, android

In my Android application I have an `Observable` `Data` class, which contains a method `download()` to download and parse some data. When this is done, it notifies its `Observer`s.

Further, I have an `Activity` and a `Service`. The `Activity` calls the `download()` method asynchronous using an `AsyncTask`.

The `Service` constantly needs to listen for updates to process the data further. This should not happen in the UI thread. I've created this little `Service` class:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        new MyWorkerThread().start();
    }

    private class MyWorkerThread extends Thread implements Observer{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            observeData();
        }

        private void observeData(){
            Data.getInstance().addObserver(this);
        }

            @Override
            public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
               // In what thread does the code placed here run?
            }
    }
}
```

Now, my question: When the `download()` method of the `Data` class notifies its `Observer`s, in which thread will the `update()` method run? Will this be in the thread of the `AsyncTask` created by the `Activity`, which prevents the code from going through the `onPostExecute()` method until the service is done? If so, would I be better off making my `MyService` an `Observer` and create a new `MyWorkerThread` each time?
Or will the code run in it's own thread by the `MyWorkerThread`?

I hope it's understandable, thanks in advance!

Comment: Observers are direct method calls. So `update` is executed by whatever calls `notifyObservers`. Your thread is long gone by then since your `run` method finishes pretty much instantly.

Comment: Okay, clear, thanks! I guess I'd better create a new Thread everytime the `notifyObservers` method is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess I'd better create a new Thread everytime the notifyObservers method is called

You can do that but you don't have to. For example using a single `HandlerThread` would accomplish the same. Also you don't have to deal with multiple threads running in parallel then.

```
public class ObserverService extends Service {

    private Looper mLooper;

    private void onDataChanged() {
        // do whatever you need.
        // This is executed in a background thread.
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        HandlerThread ht = new HandlerThread("ObserverService");
        ht.start();
        mLooper = ht.getLooper();
        final Handler handler = new Handler(mLooper) {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // executed in background HandlerThread
                onDataChanged();
            }
        };
        Observer observer = new Observer() {
            @Override
            public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
                // this is executed in whatever thread notifies
                // enqueue max 1 messages.
                handler.removeMessages(1234);
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(1234);
            }
        };
        // register observer that send message to background thread.
        Data.getInstance().addObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mLooper.quit();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is right here

> When the download() method of the Data class notifies its Observers

in the same thread as `update` method will be called (which would be in the same thread as `download` method runs - which, as I understand, notifies its Observers.

As zapl posted, `MyWorkerThread` finishes after observing data (`observeData();`).

In order to run in a different thread you should write something like:

```
private class MyWorkerThread extends Thread implements Observer{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        observeData();
    }

    private void observeData(){
        Data.getInstance().addObserver(this);
    }

        @Override
        public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
            this.start(); //will execute observeData(); in a new thread
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Observer<MyData> observer = data -> executor.execute(() -> onMyDataChanged(data));
    MyData.getInstance().observeForever(observer);
```